# How do I calculate a field that needs a where statement

Tags: sql, oracle

If I have the following dataset:

```
pk ind value
1  1   10
2  1   11
3  2   13
```

I would like to calculate the percentage (of the value) of items that have indicator 1 relative to the total value. So in simple math this would be

`(10+11)/(10+11+13)`

I do obviously know how to extract only the values with indicator 1, but I'm not sure how to divide that by total in an sql query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `case` expression to do conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when ind = 1 then value else 0 end) / sum(value)
from tablename
```

Will raise a division by zero error if there are no rows in the table. (Non-null rows, to be specific.)

I don't know Oracle, perhaps you need to multiply `value` with 1.0 to avoid integer division, always returning 0 here. I.e. do `sum(case when ind = 1 then 1.0 * value else 0 end)`.

Comment: Works perfectly!

Comment: You can use `nullif(sum(value),0)` to convert any zero to null. Also Oracle SQL has no special integer division, it's just numbers.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson, you mean 1/2 will return 0.5, and not 0?

Comment: Yes. The result would only get rounded if you put it into an integer column or PL/SQL variable, but that's just normal rounding not any special integer handling.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson, thanks for the info. According to the ANSI SQL specification the behavior is _implementation defined_. Some products truncate and others don't.

Answer (score 2):

Calculate percent for each indicators

```
SELECT
  t.ind,
  SUM(t.value) amount,
  SUM(t.value)/SUM(SUM(t.value))OVER() percent
FROM Test t
GROUP BY t.ind
```

SQL Fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f4249/5